# Genexus 16 - ¿Es posible ejecutar código Javascript desde un Evento Genexus?

Tags: genexus

Necesito ejecutar un método Javascript y quería saber si es posible hacerlo desde un evento Genexus.

**NOTA:** He probado la opción de **JSEvent**, pero esta opción cubre sólo cuando haga OnClick en un botón y en otro escenerio que no me sirve para mi problema.

Quisiera ejecutar dicho código Javascript cuando pase algún evento dentro de un Webpanel. Espero me puede ayudar.

Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago utilizando una variable `VarChar`, la cual coloco en el `Form`. Luego indico que es del tipo "Run Javascript". En el evento, le asigno el código JS que quiero ejecutar y listo.

Agrego un ejemplo gráfico de lo que expliqué arriba:

[image: Ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

El textbock en su propiedad format, debes ponerla como HTML:

```
Textlock1.Caption = "<script> if (screen.width>=992) document.getElementById(" + ' "TEXTBLOCK2"' + ").style.display = 'none';}</script>"
```